# Select Set value Can delete

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

I using kartik select2 widget for show Select2 plugin.

when init select and it running, i need set value for select 2 by set PlaceHolder for select

Example:

```
$('#select_ID').val(null).trigger("change");
$("#select2-select_ID-container .select2-selection__placeholder").text(cName);
```

So,  clear function not active. 
Like Image is ok.

[image]

And that is not ok. Because, clear icon not show.

[image]
How can i do it? and show clear button when init value.

Answer (score 0):

A placeholder is static, you shouldn't clear it. The clear action should show up after a value have been chosen.

Comment: yes, thank you, i know that i do. so case when not choose a value, i want init value from jquery. and need show clear option

Comment: Why would you need to show clear option for when there is no value? What would you like to clear when it's already clear?